# Oracle Server(Remote)

Tags: oracle, netbeans, remote-server

I am doing a project in java that uses oracle database. I built the application (using NetBeans IDE) and can connect to my Oracle database (locally). I shared my application files to my friends. They can't connect to my database. What setting do I have to change (considering both Oracle and NetBeans) so that my friends can connect to my database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you all on the same network?  What is your connection string-- are you using the thin driver or the OCI JDBC driver?  Are you using a TNS alias?  Specifying the host name?  Specifying localhost?  Are you running a firewall on your local machine?  What errors are you getting?  What troubleshooting have you tried?

Comment: 1) Within the same network my database can be connected by other machines.
2) Connection String -  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.5:1521:orcl",user,pass);
3) I am using thin driver
4) I am not using TNS alias
5) I am using SID
6) I have ESET internet security that ONs the firewall
7) Error - java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
java.lang.NullPointerException
8) I am new to database so I am not that much familiar. I turned off ESET firewall. Tried to change Thin(SID) to Thin (TNS) - failed.

Comment: _"Within the same network my database can be connected by other machines"_  So it appears to be a network routing issue.  From a machine that _cannot_ connect to the database, execute the command 'ping 192.168.1.5'   And again, we need an actual error message from a failed connection.  Oracle issues those error messages for a reason, you know.